# Is this a simple or complex sentence? "A typical characteristic of EDM is that the cavity cut by the tool electrode is larger than the tool itself."

Tags: grammar, complex-sentences

I have this sentence:

- *A typical characteristic of EDM is that the cavity cut by the tool electrode is larger than the tool itself.*

I want to determine whether it is a simple or complex sentence. A complex sentence must contain at least two clauses: one independent clause and one or more dependent clauses. The mentioned sentence includes a nominal clause "that the cavity cut by the tool electrode is larger than the tool itself", which acts as a dependent clause. The question then is whether the remaining "A typical characteristic of EDM is" can be considered an independent clause. Is it a complete thought to be classified as an independent clause?

Comment: No: _a typical characteristic of EDM_ is is not a clause, not a constituent at all, but part of a larger construction. You could, I suppose, call the sentence 'complex' because it has a main clause (the whole sentence) and a subordinate (dependent) clause marked as subordinate by the subordinator "that".

Comment: If even BillJ uses hedging ("You could, I suppose, call the sentence 'complex' ") then it is a very good idea to ask whether such classification is really helpful or needs setting aside in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> *A typical characteristic of EDM is* [*that the cavity cut by the tool*
> *electrode is larger than the tool itself*].

No: "a typical characteristic of EDM is" is not a clause, not a constituent at all, but part of a larger construction.

Traditional grammar would probably classify it as a 'complex sentence' because it has a matrix (main) clause, i.e. the sentence as a whole, and a subordinate (dependent) clause, bracketed.

Nowadays, we don't normally talk of sentences being simple, complex or compound, since many don't fit easily into those categories.

Comment: I edited the whitespace so I could reverse my downvote. The usual model of a complex sentence has an independent and dependent clause that are related to one another, the latter being a relative clause.  This does not exclude from the definition of "complex" a sentence where the dependent clause is a component of the independent clause, as is the case here.

Comment: [The usual definition of a complex clause](https://www.bristol.ac.uk/academic-language/media/BEAP/3.4/index.html) is that it uses a subordinating conjunction not a relative clause or other construct.